# Algorithmic braiding - for mother's day

Tags: code-golf

**Task:**

Your task is to create a program that, when given a number of strands and number of iterations of a braid, will tell where each strand goes. Rules are as follows:

- The number of strands will always be odd, and between 3 and 6000 (inclusive)
- When you start, the strands will be divided into 2 (almost) equal bunches, the `left` and the `right`. The `left` will have one more strand when you start.

For an input of 7:

```
/ / / / \ \ \
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

- Every iteration, the outermost strand of the side with more strands will be put in the center facing the opposite direction. The center is defined as between opposite facing strands: `////middle\\\`.

1 iteration of input 7 (strand 1 was moved to the center):

```
/ / / \ \ \ \
2 3 4 1 5 6 7
```

**Example:**

Input:

```
3 4
```

Computations:

```
1 2 3
 \
2 1 3
   /
2 3 1
 \
3 2 1
   /
3 1 2
```

Output:

```
3 1 2
```

**Rules:**

- You do not need to display the slashes for strand direction, only the numbers.
- You only need to display the numbers after the last iteration.
- Your output will be space-deliminated ids of the strands
- Input will be in the form: `strands [space] iterations`
- The number of strands will always be odd, and 3<=x<=6000
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins!

Comment: Would it not be 3 to 5999 as 6000 is not odd so you will not have 'up to 6000'?

Comment: so the output for `11 2` would be `2345611178910`?

Comment: there should be spaces between numbers in the output so that it's readable for larger inputs

Comment: @m.buettner yes, i need to add spaces

Comment: @Howard Your submission broke my change

Comment: @TheDoctor My answer was there before your change.

Comment: make the spaces optional? of course, without the spaces the result is ambiguous, but what are the odds of someone getting it accidentally right?

Comment: I think your example should read `123 -> 213 -> 231 -> 321 -> 312`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### GolfScript, 33 characters

```
~\),(@{:^1$[=]:y-.,2//y*^~}*;' '*
```

The input must be provided on stdin.

Examples (you may test [online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyIxMSAyIgoKflwpLChAezpeMSRbPV06eS0uLDIvL3kqXn59KjsnICcqCg%3D%3D&run=true)):

```
> 7 1
2 3 4 1 5 6 7

> 3 4
3 1 2

> 11 2
2 3 4 5 6 11 1 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 6):

#### Python: 179 <strike>240</strike>, 152 characters

**First, the 179**

For `N` strands and `i` iterations, this answer uses `O(1)` space and `O(N)` time. I simply compute the end position of each strand, never iterating over the intermediate positions!

**big edit:** golfed this answer by changing conditionals to boolean algebra. I also wrote a [lengthy explanation](https://gist.github.com/wrongu/cd668c49b481bd2ade23) of how it works. TL;DR: formulaic patterns, modulo division.

```py
from sys import *
N,i=map(int,stdin.readline().split())
h,t=N/2,3*N
f=lambda p:(p>N)*(t/2-(p&-2))+p/2+1
for s in xrange(N):print f((2*s+1+(s>h)*(t-4*s-2)+i*(N+1-N*(s!=h)))%(2*N)),
```

**Now the 152**

This is more reasonably golfed python. (edit: thanks to Alex Thornton for editing from 165 to 152)

```py
from sys import*;l=map;r=range;n,m=l(int,stdin.readline().split());b=r(1,n+1)
for k in r(m):v=b.pop((0,n-1)[k%2]);b.insert(n/2,v)
print' '.join(l(str,b)
```

Comment: Have golfed it even further down to 151 if you're interested: http://pastebin.com/1pbwax6s

Comment: simple changes, but very effective. thanks!

Comment: I think you could cut it down even further by removing the `l` and `v` variables and changing the `insert` to a slice assignment.

Comment: I'm sure the golf could be shorter. Honestly I just expected comments on the first one if anything!

Comment: I wrote up an explanation anyway and updated the post :)

Comment: And all the way down to 104: http://pastebin.com/Jb0QdQu3

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2 (109) / Python 3 (121)

**Python 2**

```python
s,n=map(int,raw_input().split())
b=range(s)
for i in range(n):b[s/2:s/2]=[b.pop(0-i%2)]
for x in b:print x+1,
```

**Python 3**

```python
s,n=map(int,input().split())
b=list(range(s))
for i in range(n):b[s//2:s//2]=[b.pop(0-i%2)]
for x in b:print(x+1,end=' ')
```

The code must have been bribed by Python 2 to showcase its golfing advantages over Python 3: ranges being lists, division rounding down to an int, print not starting a newline.
The weird `0-i%2` is because `-i%2` evaluates as `(-i)%2`.

There's probably a more efficient approach than iterating, namely computing each final result directly. The braiding operation has period 2*s, so it can't be that complicated.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 105

Just a lot of set manipulation.  Push, pop, reverse and shift!  I tried not converting inputs to integers, but it added about 20 characters.

```
n,i=$*.map(&:to_i)
f=l=(1..n).to_a
t=r=l.pop(n/2).reverse
i.times{f,t=t<<f.shift,f}
$><<(l+r.reverse)*' '
```

`l` and `r` (`left` and `right`) are the "thread" queues. `right` is reversed so we start pulling from the outside.

`t` and `f` (`to` and `from`) start off as `right` and `left`, respectively, but as we go we keep swapping them so we can always shift the last "thread" from `from` and push it to `to` (`f,t=t<<f.shift,f`).  This saves a LOT of space.

Then we just re-reverse `right` at the end.

#### Changelog:

2.2 **105** oh yeah, map can take a proc

2.1 **108** And actually, just flip things as part of manipulation.

2.0 **116** don't use that temporary array. Instead use two pointer variables we can manipulate and keep re-pointing. Then only display the end

1.0 **123** initial idea

Answer (score 0):

### Java, 270 chars

golfed:

```
import java.util.*;class B{public static void main(String[] a){int n=Integer.valueOf(a[0]),t=Integer.valueOf(a[1]),i=0;List<Integer> r=new ArrayList<Integer>();for(;i<n;i++){r.add(i+1);}for(i=0;i<t;i++){int k=i%2==0?0:n-1;r.add(n/2,r.remove(k));}System.out.println(r);}}
```

un-golfed:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Braid {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
        int iterations = Integer.valueOf(args[1]);

        //populate array
        List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i < num; i++) {
            arr.add(i+1);
        }
        for (int i=0; i < iterations; i++) {
            int index = i%2==0?0:num-1; 
            arr.add(num/2, arr.remove(index));
        }
        System.out.println(arr);
    }
}
```

[Run online](http://ideone.com/a7Ohjh)